# How to render all the data associated with one entry through link Using Django ?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am learning  Django and created an app "myapp", having defferent components as per given bellow:

Models looks like this: 
Model.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class CountryDetails(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    T_attack = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="attack")
    year = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    Deaths = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    NEWS_ID = models.CharField(max_length=254, verbose_name="NEWS_ID")


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Deaths
```

View looks like this: 
view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Country, CountryDetails 

def home(request):
    c_list = Country.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'myapp/home.html', {'c_list':c_list})

def details(request, pk):
    c_details =  get_object_or_404(CountryDetails, pk)
    return render(request, 'myapp/home.html', {'c_details':c_details})
```

Urls looks line this:
urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views 

urlpatterns = [

url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
url(r'^myapp/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.details, name='details'),

]
```

For rendering the view html looks like this: 
home.html:

```
 {% for c in c_list %}

 <h1><a href="{% url 'details' pk=c.pk %}">{{ c }}</a></h3></br>

 {% endfor %}
```

In short, I have created an app, having some data for various countries like this

Raw data:

```
name   T_attack   year  Deaths  News_ID

India    12       2006   12       NDTV
India    110      2009   1        DEAN
PAKISTAN 9        2002   10       XYZT
PAKISTAN 11       2021   11       XXTV
India    12       2023   120      NDNV
India    10       2012   12       DEAN
PAKISTAN 12       2022   12       DLRS
Canada   1        2001   1        DLTV
USA      2        2011   13       NTTV
```

"Home.html" of "myapp" renders a list of all the available countries like this :

```
INDIA 
PKISTAN
USA
CANADA
```

I am expecting that when I click, lets assume on India, it should render all the available details on a second "html" page,  say, "detailed.html", associated with India like this:

```
name   T_attack   year  Deaths  News_ID
India    12       2006   12       NDTV
India    110      2009   1        DEAN
India    12       2023   120      NDNV
India    10       2012   12       DEAN
```

But when I execute my code  its showing some error like this:

```
ValueError at /myapp/1/
need more than 1 value to unpack
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/1/
Django Version: 1.10
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
need more than 1 value to unpack
Exception Location: /home/jai/Desktop/trytable/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py in build_filter, line 1130
Python Executable:  /home/jai/Desktop/trytable/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/jai/Desktop/trytable/test_project',
 '/home/jai/Desktop/trytable/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/jai/Desktop/trytable/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
 '/home/jai/Desktop/trytable/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/jai/Desktop/trytable/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/jai/Desktop/trytable/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/jai/Desktop/trytable/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/jai/Desktop/trytable/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 15 Jul 2017 16:03:33 +0000
```

Kindly help me out. Thanks

Comment: Where is the template code that uses `c_details`?

Comment: @AlexHall, I thought At list it should return something to render so I dint write  anything for that now,   Can you suggest me how should it look likes bcz, as I am working on Django for last three days only., and now my brain not allowing me to understand. I have tried and explore all the tutorial and threads on Internet my nothing has worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c_details =  get_object_or_404(CountryDetails, pk)
```

you should replace it with

```
c_details = CountryDetails.objects.filter(country__pk=pk)
```

In your urls you are using the `pk` of the country so you need to filter all the rows that are related to a country. The `filter` query does that.
And to show the details in your template you can do something like this.

```
{% for c in c_details %}

 <h1>{{ c.T_attack }}</h3></br>
 <!-- and so on for the other fields also. -->

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Greatttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt Its working perfectly, Thanks a lottttttttttttt :)

Comment: Only one Question,  as you have used "country__pk", is there any special rule to write like this or its could be "anything__pk"

Comment: You can use `__` to filter on a property of the foreign key class. `Country` is a foreign key. It can not be used with anything.

Comment: Thanks for explanation and your answer :)